# The indexing of heap sort algorithm from Geeks for Geeks seems little off

Tags: python, heapsort

Just a quick question. I have been looking at the HeapSort algorithm from Geeks for Geeks in Python, and When it's building maxheap under heapSort function, the range goes from (n,-1,-1) should it not be (n-1,-1,-1)? Below is the code snippet

```
# Python program for implementation of heap Sort 

# To heapify subtree rooted at index i. 
# n is size of heap 
def heapify(arr, n, i): 
    largest = i # Initialize largest as root 
    l = 2 * i + 1     # left = 2*i + 1 
    r = 2 * i + 2     # right = 2*i + 2 

    # See if left child of root exists and is 
    # greater than root 
    if l < n and arr[i] < arr[l]: 
        largest = l 

    # See if right child of root exists and is 
    # greater than root 
    if r < n and arr[largest] < arr[r]: 
        largest = r 

    # Change root, if needed 
    if largest != i: 
        arr[i],arr[largest] = arr[largest],arr[i] # swap 

        # Heapify the root. 
        heapify(arr, n, largest) 

# The main function to sort an array of given size 
def heapSort(arr): 
    n = len(arr) 

    # Build a maxheap. 
    for i in range(n, -1, -1): 
        heapify(arr, n, i) 

    # One by one extract elements 
    for i in range(n-1, 0, -1): 
        arr[i], arr[0] = arr[0], arr[i] # swap 
        heapify(arr, i, 0)
```

Comment: Note how `heapify()` never uses `n` index - it always stops short. It seems `n` in `heapify()` is meant to represent the *length* of the heap, not the *last element index* of the heap

Comment: Aha, You're right. Good point! Thanks for pointing it out!